# Store images dynamically in a VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, image

My application has a section where the user can create products and assign a bitmap image to each product. The products are all displayed in a listview control.

The products should then be stored so that when the user next opens the application, all the products they added during runtime appear with the correct imagery.

How would I go about storing these images in the VB project, and which method is most efficient programmatically?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user can choose among a set of predefined images, just put them in a project folder and store the image file name in a field of the Products table. 
If the user can upload images, save the uploaded file in a public accessible folder and store the file name in a field of the Products table.
The root of the url linking to the image is always the same so you just save the file name and prefix the root when calling it from url.

Comment: Thanks for replying! The user uploads images rather than selecting from a set of predefined images. Where would be the best place to create this folder? In the project folder? User's documents, etc.?

Comment: It depends on the data to store: if there is huge data, I suggest you use some storage cloud service like Google Cloud Storage, so you can rely on a scalable platform. Usually, you store files in very fast and responsive environments, so as to be retrieved very fast. If you don't care about performance and have a small amount of data to store, go for storing in a "Files" project folder.

Comment: Thanks, as there's only a small amount of data to store, I'll go with the latter option!